# switching 2d array values as a response to click events in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, 2d

I am making a candy-crush like game in Visual Basic. I have started and have worked out a code based off a 2D Label array. It contains tiles of 6 different colors who are randomly generated in the beginning. Now I got to the actual game part and I got stuck.

I am able to click a tile in the array but I can't seem to switch their positions so that I would be able to line up three or more colors vertically or horizontally.

I am not necessarily asking for specific code, but I was wondering how more experienced coders (like on this platform) would solve this issue.

Here is the piece of Code that deals with the switching tiles after they both have been clicked:

```
Private Sub Click_H(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim l1 As Label = DirectCast(sender, Label)
    Dim l2 As Label = DirectCast(sender, Label)
    Dim temp As Label

    For k As Integer = 0 To 2 Step 1
        For i As Integer = 0 To 9
            For j As Integer = 0 To 9

                If k = 0 Then

                    If l1.Equals(rooster(i, j)) Then
                        rooster(i, j).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
                        ClickCounter += 1
                        l1 = rooster(i, j)
                        temp = rooster(i, j)
                        rooster(i, j) = rooster(i + 1, j)
                        rooster(i + 1, j) = temp
                    End If
                End If

                If k = 1 Then

                    If l1.Equals(rooster(i, j)) Then
                        rooster(i, j).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
                        ClickCounter += 1
                        l2 = rooster(i, j)

                        If l2.Equals(rooster(i + 1, j)) Then
                            temp = rooster(i, j)
                            rooster(i, j) = rooster(i + 1, j)
                            rooster(i + 1, j) = temp
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

"rooster is the word for "field" in a different language. Any help?

Comment: You need better variable name. Also, l1 and l2 are the same at the begining of the sub. What does ClickCounter do? Personally, I would switch the content of the label, not the reference (ex: switch the image inside the label).

Add a method "GetPositionFromLabel(l1)" that would return the x, y position of the label passed as parameter. This would remove those for loop out of the main logic and into a sub method.

Comment: ClickCounter is the value of the number of clicks performed. When the number of clicks reaches two, the first clicked label and the second clicked label are supposed to switch places. How do you think I should differentiate between two clicks (l1 and l2)? Also the GetPositionFromLabel function, should I pass the x and y as parameters through l1 or manually? Thanks for your advice though.

Comment: If you print out ClickCounter at the end of the sub, it'll be equal to 2 on the first click because if your k loop. Try to split up you function in smaller ones, it might help you fix your logic.

Comment: You have your K loop 0 to 2 but code is only executed for values 0 and 1. Seems like an extra outer loop for nothing. The inner loop will loop 10 times and do nothing.

Comment: Thank you for the translation of rooster. Is rooster a 2 dimensional array of labels? Actually, I think you could have a class of Tile. It could have a column property, a row property and a color property.

Comment: You will have to store the first clicked tile, perhaps in a form level variable of Type Label named TileClicked. In the click event check if TileClicked is Nothing and set it to sender if it is and Exit Sub, Else this is the second click so proceed with your processing. Don't forget to set TileClicked back to nothing at the end of the procedure.

Comment: @Mary I thank you for the advice of using a different class for the base of the programme, but since I am a literal beginner I would like to build up to that because I don't think I can connect different classes efficiently. The tileclicked label variable I will definetly try out. I really appreciate all the help :)

Comment: Also I had a different question. How will I be able to compare tiles who are immediate neighbours without going out of bounds? Like when I use the for loops with lower and upperbounds I am always out of bounds if Ie.g. want to compare rooster(i,j) and rooster(i+1,j).